# datediff not working coldfusion

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

Trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. I am calling a cfm page which checks after every 10 seconds that if the `diff` is `YES`, it should actually enable the fields, even if I am refreshing the whole or not..

Here is my jquery Code

```
setInterval(function() {
        $("#myDiv").load('lockout.cfm');
}, 10000);
```

Here is my CFM Code

```
<cfsavecontent variable="head">
<cfset diff = structKeyExists(session,'lockzoneTime') AND session.lockzoneTime NEQ '' AND DateDiff("n","#session.lockzoneTime#","#TimeFormat(TimeFormat(now(),'HH:mm'))#") GTE 5>
<cfif diff IS 'Yes'>
<cfset session.countTries = IIF((session.countTries EQ 10),DE('0'),DE('#session.countTries#'))>
<cfset session.lockzoneTime = ''>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('useremail').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('useremail').value = '';
    document.getElementById('password').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('password').value = '';
    document.getElementById('login').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('ajaxNotify').innerHTML = '';
</script>
</cfif>
<cfif diff IS 'No'>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(document.getElementById('useremail').disabled == true) {
        document.getElementById('useremail').disabled = true;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('password').disabled == true) {
        document.getElementById('password').disabled = true;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('login').disabled == true) {
        document.getElementById('login').disabled = true;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('login').disabled == true) {
        document.getElementById('Notify').innerHTML = 'You have been temporarily locked out.';
    }
</script>
</cfif>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfhtmlhead text="#head#">

session.lockzoneTime
```

is setup on different page as:

```
TimeFormat(DateAdd('n', 5, TimeFormat(now(),'HH:mm')),'HH:mm')
```

Problem seems to here, it keeps giving me `NO` in the `cfdump`

```
<cfset diff = structKeyExists(session,'lockzoneTime') AND session.lockzoneTime NEQ '' AND DateDiff("n","#session.lockzoneTime#","#TimeFormat(TimeFormat(now(),'HH:mm'))#") GTE 5>
```

Comment: You nest TimeFormat into DateAdd; doesn't look healhy to me

Comment: hmm, so what's wrong in here, timeformat but i tried the code in cflive.net, i do not understand what is going wrong

Comment: Timeformat returns a string.  Dateadd works best with datetime objects.

Comment: does your session.lockzoneTime have to be formatted as just a time? You're better off if you can just store the raw date there.

Comment: so @dan, what will be the best approach i can try here

Comment: Try this: http://trycf.com/editor/gist/760b3c718b729f84c539/acf11?theme=merbivore_soft

Comment: your code and mine code is almost same @abram, what seems to be the difference,

Comment: mine sets `lockzonetime` to  `now()` (raw date) while your's sets `lockzonetime` to a string (per timeFormat())

Comment: @adram, Can you please make your gist as an answer, that worked for me, Thanks so i can accept.

Answer (score 3):

As others have alluded to, date functions such as [`dateAdd()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/DateAdd) and [`dateDiff()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/DateDiff) take *date/time objects* as their arguments, not strings. At the very least they expect a string which resembles a date (eg something in the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`) which CF will have a chance of being able to parse as a date/time. your strings which are in format `hh:mm` do *not* resemble dates, so CF's attempts to make sense of them as dates will be... erm... "error prone".

Recode to use the functions as intended, and see how you go.

As a rule of thumb functions with the word `format` in them (eg: [`timeFormat()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/TimeFormat)) should only ever be used as one is outputting a value. They should not be used in logic.